# Decompress Gzip String C# Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, gzip, compression

I am developping my first windows phone 8 App. I am trying to get a compressed json from a server, however, I am having problems to descompress it.

After reading for hours, I have tried two ways:

-> AutoDecompress using Microsoft.Bcl.Compression:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
if (handler.SupportsAutomaticDecompression)
{
    handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
}
var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
var str = await httpClient2.GetStringAsync(url);
```

But the result is still compressed.

->Get the info compressed, convert it to a byte[] and try to decompress de byte[].

```
var result = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
// convert string to stream
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result);
var bigStream = new GZipStream(new MemoryStream(byteArray), CompressionMode.Decompress);
var bigStreamOut = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
bigStream.CopyTo(bigStreamOut);
string s = bigStreamOut.ToString();
```

-bigStream properties:
-BufferSize  16384
-CanRead  true
-CanSeek  false
-CanWrite  true
-Comment  null
-Crc32  0
-FileName  null
-FlushMode  none
-LastModified  null
-Position 0
-Lenght, TotalIn and TotalOut throw exceptions.

Btw, the json is compressed using GZip and it is working perfectly in iOS version.

Thx

Comment: I wonder - shouldn't the client return decompressed stream already (if it uses content-encoding header correctly)? Are you using HttpClient PCL and this package: http://www.nuget.org/packages/HttpClient.Compression/ ?

Comment: Hi, I tried to use automatic decompression as follows: var handler = new CompressedHttpClientHandler();
handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip |
DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
var str = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);  However, it throws an exception: HttpClientHandler.AutomaticDecompression is not supported on this platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the official Microsoft NuGet package [Microsoft Compression](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Compression/).
[Here are even some guides](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/06/06/portable-compression-and-httpclient-working-together.aspx), how to use it together with [HttpClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Compression/).

Comment: I tried that before but the result was still compressed. I have updated the question including the code for this option... thx

Comment: The problem was in the server's side... Thx